# check the value of the radio button with the given value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to implement the following code:

```
  <input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
          <input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="no" style="margin-left:30px;    outline:0;"/>No</div>
```

in my javascript:

```
  <script>
if ($("input[name='yesno2']").val() == "no") {
  alert("ddd");
 }
  </script>
```

if I check no, it should show me the alert window, but it didn't show. sorry if I just show you part of the code, anyone could show me what am I doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
<input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="no" style="margin-left:30px;    outline:0;"/>No</div>
<br/><input type="button" id="btn1" value="GetRadioChecked">


 $("#btn1").click(function(){

        if($("input[name=yesno2]:checked ").val()=="no")
        {
            alert("no clicked");
        }
        else if($("input[name=yesno2]:checked").val()=="yes")
        {
             alert("yes checked ");
        }
        else        
       {
           alert("nothing checked !")
       }

    });
```

Working sample
http://jsfiddle.net/WxmpJ/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use the [jQuery change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$("input[name='yesno2']").change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "no") {
      alert("ddd");
     }

});
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/hnqSb/

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind an event, such as click or change:

```
$("input[name='yesno2']").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == "no") {
    alert("ddd");
   }
});
```

The reason for this is simple: Your initial code would have executed immediately and the value would not have been "no" at that time. You want to hold off and evaluate the code at the point where you actually need the value. This may be on change or it may be during another step in your process, such as during form submission.

Answer (score 1):

One fundamental issue is the form of the selector you're using will always give  you the value of the first input matched.  You should be applying a handler, then using `this` inside the handler to find the element that actually generated the event.  You can get the value from that element and check it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { // apply handlers after document loads
       $('[name="yesno2"]').change( function() { // apply a change handler to both inputs
            if ($(this).val() == "no") {// get value from modified input, not first input
                alert('ddd');
            }
       });
   });
</script>
```

The reason we use a change handler instead of a click handler is that the value of a radio may change based on clicking the associated label element, assuming you have it set up correctly, rather than only by clicking the radio button.

See an example fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Q7geW/